# VB.Net - Deleting multiple selected rows in a Datagridview

Tags: vb.net

I cannot find a way to delete the selected rows not only on the datagridview, but also on the SQL Server Database. How should I do that in VB.Net?

Comment: do iterate to all selected rows and do it with  delete query ..

Answer (score -1):

Delete the selected items from the database using something like `delete from table where x = @x`. Then delete the same selected items from the DataGridView.

Comment: -1. Doing two deletes is redundant. Delete from the data source, commit, and changes will be published to the database. Doing it the other way around will not work, because OP needs selected rows to be deleted, and there is nothing selected on the DB side, so you have no criteria for deletion.